# General method for solving $\sigma(n) = x$

Tags: number-theory

General method for solving $\sigma(n) = x$. I'm looking for a general way to show all number n such that the sum of the divisors of n (including 1 and n itself) equal $x$.

For example, there is a question to show all the numbers such that $\sigma(n) = 28$ and I believe the only answer is 12, however, I'm not sure how to rigorously show that this is the only result (apart from manually going through every number, but there's surely a nicer way?). Is there a nicer general method for any $x$?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, that's not related to what I asked. I know the general formula.

Comment: See the [links](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2701980/find-all-positive-integers-n-such-that-sigma-n-91) on this site, how to do it.